# Regenerate Graphite dashboard

Tags: graphite

I have a bunch of machines pushing data into a dashboard in Graphite and the number of machines is constantly growing so I am wondering whether is a way to automatically regenerate a dashboard based on the machines that are providing various stats.

Like, I don't want to manually add machines to the dashboard each time I add new ones - I want to have a background task running for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this by reporting metric names in a task oriented format and wild cards.
Example: `<site>.<purpose>.<hostname>.<platform>.<stats>`

You can also just use a wildcard anywhere (`<site>.*.*.*.<stat>`) and as long as that metric exists at that level it will be included in the graph.